# Smarty regex_replace with case insensitive

Tags: regex, smarty, case-insensitive

I need with smarty `regex_replace`, replace a variable with a bolded variable, example :

I have a variable `$title` with "This is a title".

I have a keyword `$keyword` with "Title".

I need to replace in `$title`, `$keyword` by `'<b>'$keyword'</b>'`, and this with case insensitive. If I have "TiTLe" in `$keyword`, this should work.

For now I have : `` {$title|regex_replace:"/`$keyword`/i":"<b>`$keyword`</b>"} ``

My problem is, with this, I replace `title` by `<b>Title</b>` and I want to keep the initial case from `$title` like : `<b>title</b>`

How can i do that ?

Comment: You can surround any code in double backticks too, which allows you to use single backticks within the code - I've edited your post to do this for you :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips ;)

Comment: Try ``{$title|regex_replace:"/(`$keyword`)/i":'<b>\1</b>'}``